# Is there a way to fix this problem in the code?

Tags: python, deep-learning, bayesian, bayesian-networks, gaussian-process

```
for i in range(103): # we will run 100 experiments of GP => 100 befief updates of the good region.
    existing_bayesian_optimizer = os.path.isfile(out_dir + "ev_file_RL_ANN") # ev_file is a simple txt file (empty @ beginning) "warning \n"
    if GP:
        if existing_bayesian_optimizer :
            evals = pd.read_csv(out_dir+"ev_file_RL_ANN", index_col=0, delimiter="\t")
            Y = np.array([[x] for x in evals["Y"]],dtype=np.float32)   # Just want add dimensions ??
            X = np.array(evals.filter(regex="var*"),dtype=np.float32)
            myBopt = GPyOpt.methods.BayesianOptimization(f=myfunc, domain=bounds, constraints=None, Y=Y,X=X, initial_design_numdata=3, maximize=False)
            **myBopt.run_optimization(max_iter=1, verbosity=True, report_file=out_dir+"bayesian_optimizer_RL_ANN_log.txt", models_file=out_dir+"bayes_opt_RL_ANN_model", eps=0)** This is the line 198
            myBopt.save_evaluations(out_dir+"ev_file_RL_ANN")
            myBopt.save_models(out_dir+"mod_file_RL_ANN")
        else :
            myBopt = GPyOpt.methods.BayesianOptimization(f=myfunc, domain= bounds, constraints=None, initial_design_numdata=3, maximize=False)
            myBopt.run_optimization(max_iter=1, verbosity=True, report_file=out_dir+"bayesian_optimizer_RL_ANN_log.txt", models_file=out_dir+"bayes_opt_RL_ANN_model", eps=0)
            myBopt.save_evaluations(out_dir+"ev_file_RL_ANN") #if not saved, then create an empty file in result_new_train called "ev_file_RL_ANN"
            myBopt.save_models(out_dir+"mod_file_RL_ANN")
    else:
        pass
```

So when I was running the bayseian optimization here, it keeps shows me that this error[enter image description here][1]

Can someone help me with this? Thank you so much!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHCrC.png

Comment: Hey is there anyone can help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please copy and paste the full error message, formatted as code, instead of using a screenshot.